# Gratis ceemple-like IDE

Tags: gratis, c++, ide, matlab, rad

Ceemple was a product worked on Eclipse IDE, which uses C++ for rapid development, bundled with losts of lib. So, for example, we can solve a math problem with concise syntax, then plot it with Python/Matplotlib in Ceemple. The productivity is high.

However, Ceemple has been replaced with https://www.zapcc.com/, which is only available for selected beta tester for a long time.

So, my question is: is there any free( or at least free in academic research) or opensource Ceemple-like IDE for rapid C++ programming( currently, I need math/matrix calculation and figure plot mainly. I am using python, but sometimes python is slow, and I need to share C/C++ code with my colleagues)?